# Is ${n^2}/D(n^2) \in \mathbb{N}$, if $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let $x \in \mathbb{N}$, the set of positive integers.  The sum of the divisors of $x$ is denoted by $\sigma(x)$.  Denote the deficiency of $x$ by $D(x):=2x-\sigma(x)$, and the sum of the aliquot parts of $x$ by $s(x):=\sigma(x)-x$.  Finally, denote the abundancy index of $x$ by $I(x):=\sigma(x)/x$.

If $m$ is odd and $\sigma(m)=2m$, then $m$ is called an odd perfect number.  Euler proved that an odd perfect number (if one exists) must have the form $m=q^k n^2$ where $q$ is the special / Euler prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Here is my question:

> Is ${n^2}/D(n^2) \in \mathbb{N}$, if $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number?

**MY ATTEMPT**

From the fundamental equality
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}$$
one can derive
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$$
so that we ultimately have
$$\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}=\frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q^k)}=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)).$$

Thus, we have
$$y:=\frac{n^2}{D(n^2)}=\frac{{n^2}}{s(q^k)\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))}=\frac{{n^2}D(q^k)}{2s(q^k)s(n^2)}.$$

In particular, we obtain
$$\frac{n^2}{D(n^2)}=\frac{{n^2}}{s(q^k)\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))}=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2s(q^k)}.$$

Using the reasoning in this [blog post](https://arnienumbers.blogspot.com/2017/03/on-biconditional-for-odd-perfect.html), we obtain
$$\frac{q}{2} + \frac{1}{2{q^{k-1}}} - \frac{1}{2q^k} < y \leq \frac{q}{2} + \frac{1}{2{q^{k-1}}}.$$

Equality holds if and only if $k=1$.

That is, it appears that $y \in \mathbb{N}$ if and only if $k=1$ (i.e., the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture holds).

So the question "Is ${n^2}/D(n^2) \in \mathbb{N}$?" is equivalent to asking whether $k=1$, for $m=q^k n^2$ an odd perfect number with special / Euler prime $q$.

Comment: Unless n is prime is your first line necessarily true?

Comment: @SteveB, the first line
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}$$
is necessarily true since $m=q^k n^2$ is perfect implies that $\sigma(m)=2m$.

Now use the fact that $\sigma$ is (weakly) multiplicative and that $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  You will also need to use the fact that $\gcd(q^k, \sigma(q^k))=1$.

Comment: @SteveB, by the way, it is known (by work of [Nielsen, 2015](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2015-84-295/S0025-5718-2015-02941-X/)) that $\omega(n) \geq 9$, where $\omega(x)$ is the *number of distinct prime factors* of $x$.  In other words, it *is known* that $n$ *must be composite*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\frac{n^2}{D(n^2)}\in\mathbb N\iff k=1$$

*Proof* :

If $\frac{n^2}{D(n^2)}\in\mathbb N$, then we have
$$\frac{2n^2}{D(n^2)}=\frac{2n^2}{2n^2-\sigma(n^2)}=\frac{2n^2}{2n^2-\frac{2n^2q^k}{\sigma(q^k)}}=\frac{2n^2}{2n^2-\frac{2n^2q^k(q-1)}{q^{k+1}-1}}=q+\frac{q-1}{q^k-1}\in\mathbb N$$
from which we have to have
$$\frac{q-1}{q^k-1}\in\mathbb N$$
from which we have to have
$$\frac{q-1}{q^k-1}\ge 1\implies q-1\ge q^k-1\implies q^{k-1}\le 1$$
from which $k=1$ follows.

If $k=1$, then 
$$\frac{n^2}{D(n^2)}=\frac{q^{2}-1}{2(q-1)}=\frac{q+1}{2}\in\mathbb N\quad\square$$

Comment: Thank you for this splendid answer, @mathlove!  +1!  =)

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita Dris: Just curious. Are there any reasons you have not accepted only this answer? :)

Comment: My apologies, I missed this one!  Gladly accepting your answer now.  =)

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebita-Dris I believe that revisiting this could lead to a determination of whether I was correct and crazy or just crazy in the other question, but rather than the predicate $\frac{n^2}{D(n^2)}\in\mathbb N$, we partition $\mathbb Q$ into several disjoint subsets, which are defined so by inequalities on $\frac{n^2}{D(n^2)}$, and then conducting the same for $\frac{n}{D(n)}$, their difference as they appear in my original inequality can be demonstrated to have the upper bound $\frac{3}{4}$

Comment: @AdamL:  The inequality that we are considering in your answer to that other question is for $\frac{D(n^2)}{s(n^2)}$ and not just $\frac{n^2}{D(n^2)}$.  But any way, I get your point - it may all amount to some clever algebraic manipulations.  =)

Comment: Ah sorry sorry sorry I sometimes post comments while I am falling asleep :-P